# htaccess root domain and sub domain direction

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dns, server

Hi can you help me about this ? because I dont know how I am supposed to solve it.

I am getting the  problem if I write mysite.com/australia/ or mysite.com/australia/something  ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND but if I write www.mysite.com/australia/ site is perfectly open

I am getting another problem if I write my subdomain name like this www.test.mysite.com/ it is showing **Server not found** but if I try test.mysite.com/ or photo.mysite.com/ then site is perfectly open 
how can I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the apache conf file and add a server alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com 
DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html